# how to write get call based on foreign key variable?

Tags: spring-boot

I have tried this way but I am not getting it.

```java
@GetMapping("/getRoleByCompanyId/{company}")
public Optional<Role> getRoleByCompanyId(@PathVariable Company company) {
    Optional<Role> role = roleService.getRoleByCompanyId(company);
    return role;
}
```

Comment: We will need to see more code in order to help you. Please share your Role and Company models, the RoleService and also the repository that gets the data from the database. Thanks!

Comment: I am getting issue in above method only.

Comment: But what issue? Given that single piece of code, we can't help you. I don't see anything wrong there, but we would need the code that I mentioned before to be sure.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.